Pycharm fail to detect usage
I have a class where all functions are classmethods
When i try to find usage on a function that is being used by another class method, it doesnt find any usages.
I also had other occasions where i couldnt find usages but i ignored it until now. Im not sure what the pattern of what exactly it fails to find usages for, but it does seem like its for class methods.
If i copy-paste to another file or another project, it does find the usage.
I already invalidated cache many times. On this specific case it doesnt help, on other cases with similar issue it did temporarily fix the issue.
EDIT: Example -
class MyClass:

   @classmethod
   def caller_function(cls):
       cls.func()

   @classmethod
   def func(cls):  # cant find usages for this function
      ...


Your problem is unclear. Please share the relevant code and if your question is about what the IDE shows you, include a screenshot of that as well. And what exactly do you mean by "detect usage" and "find usage" in this context?

Just out of curiosity, why have a class that only has classmethods? Why not just put all the classmethods in a separate module?

@NotAName i prefer all my functions be part of a class since its more readable
